# Send and Receive from and to different ports simultaneously python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, client-server, simultaneous

[image]

I have 3 programs(**clientA.py, ClientB.py, Server_X.py**) in first machine and 1 program (*machine_Y.py*) in 2nd machine.
I need to connect as a picture and send data simultaneously from two clients to the server on host Y, modify this data and send to the server in host X.

---

Cant connect to machine ***more than one socket at a time***. says connection refused.

---

I tested my code on localhost which in this case two machines is same.
Can you advise some solution to this problem?

Client A

```
import socket
import time
import threading
def client_cam():
    # create socket and bind host
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect(('localhost', 9000))
    connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')
    try:
        count=1
        while True:
            data = 'from CAMERA: '
            client_socket.send(b'Camera')
            time.sleep(1)
            count+=1
    finally:
        connection.close()
        client_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client_cam()
```

Client B is same above except port number

machine_Y.py

```
....# here some handlers for VideoStreamHandler , SensorDataHandler
class ThreadServer(object):

    def server_thread(host, port):
        server = SocketServer.TCPServer((host, port), VideoStreamHandler)
        server.serve_forever()

    def server_thread2(host, port):
        server = SocketServer.TCPServer((host, port), SensorDataHandler)
        server.serve_forever()

    def motor_client(host,port):
        client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client_socket.connect((host, port))
        connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')
        try:
            count = 1
            while True:
                data = 'from Motor: '
                client_socket.send(b'motor')
                time.sleep(1)
                count += 1
        finally:
            connection.close()
            client_socket.close()

    motor_thread = threading.Thread(target=motor_client('localhost',9003))
    video_thread = threading.Thread(target=server_thread('localhost', 9000))
    distance_thread = threading.Thread(target=server_thread2('localhost', 9001))

    video_thread.start()
    distance_thread.start()
    motor_thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ThreadServer()
```

Server_X.py

```
import SocketServer
import threading

class MotorStreamHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    data = " "

    def handle(self):

        try:
            while self.data:
                self.data = self.request.recv(1024)
                print(self.data)
        finally:
            print("Connection closed on thread Motor")
class ThreadServer(object):
    def server_thread(host, port):
        server = SocketServer.TCPServer((host, port), MotorStreamHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    motor_thread = threading.Thread(target=server_thread('localhost',9003))
    motor_thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ThreadServer()
```

Comment: not Instagram or twitter, #tags don't work here.

Comment: "Connection Refused" indicates nothing is listening to the port you're attempting to connect to. Sounds like you are simply not starting your programs in the correct order. It appears to me that you need to start the Server_X code first, then the Machine_Y code, then the machine X clients or you will get connection refused (which will generate exceptions and kill the program since you don't catch them). (Also, it's confusing that you show the client on machine Y as a separate box in the picture, implying it's a separate program -- it's just your `motor_client` *thread*, right?)

Comment: Right, the client in machine y is motor_client thread